# How to change new line indentation in atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to configure my Atom editor in a way that after I click Enter, the new line starts with an indentation of 4 spaces, and not with a single Tab as it is configured by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **settings**.

Go to **Editor** sidebar item

Make sure **Soft Tabs** is **checked**

Below, set **TabType** to "auto"

Set **Tab Length** (a tab is normally 4 spaces)

Comment: What if you set that to 2 and you are still getting 4 spaces after a new line?