# Atom editor: indentation adding extra unwanted spaces

Tags: editor, indentation, atom-editor, auto-indent

When hitting enter in Atom editor for python code the cursor at the new line adds two extra spaces. So it doesn't end up where it should, i.e. two spaces in as in the rest of the code.

[image]

I have already followed the suggestions mentioned here, i.e. tablength=2, softtab with auto mode: [How to change new line indentation in atom editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594294/how-to-change-new-line-indentation-in-atom-editor)

In vim it seems this is set by the `shiftwidth` keyword (i.e. =4 means same problem as above, =2 means it works). I couldn't find this keyword for Atom though.

Comment: I've found tab type auto to be flaky/not work well. Just pick tabs or spaces. Also note you can set this on a per-syntax basis, along with the width, e.g. you can go to packages and set "spaces", "4" in the python syntax, but set "tabs", "8" in Makefile syntax, so you don't need to use a global setting for all languages.

Comment: I tried playing around with Python-specific settings without luck. However, it seems to work now after adding `tabLength: 2` under ".python.source": editor: in the config.cson file.